# Optimizing a EF Core "upsert" operation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to "optimize" the command below. In other words, to make it suit my needs using best practices. I found a lot of posts regarding the "upsert" operation and there were a lot of solutions and in the end, I'm not sure which one is best.

> The term upsert is a combination of the words “update” and “insert.” In the context of relational databases, an upsert is a database operation that will update an existing row if a specified value already exists in a table, and insert a new row if the specified value doesn't already exist.

There are only two tables (the database structure can be find below), and there are different event types for which we have these three booleans. Administrators can change these global notification settings on demand. If the record for a specific event type id doesn't exist, it should load it at runtime. Since these settings can be updated concurrently by many administrators at the same time, I think I should handle `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` https://github.com/petercwq/EFCorePractice/blob/master/EFCorePractice/DbContextConcurrencyExtension.cs. What do you think?

I'm not so good at EF Core, so I would like to know your opinion. I also had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557829/update-row-if-it-exists-else-insert-logic-with-entity-framework and I feel like instead of using a stored procedure or an atomic transaction, I could use `Update` which cuts off the round trips to the database? I mean I wouldn't need to do `.FindAsync` and then insert/update.

> This is something that should be done at the database engine level, in a stored procedure. Otherwise, you'll have to wrap the detect/update/insert in a transaction.

```cs
public sealed class UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommand : IRequest
{
    public Guid EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool InternalNotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool EmailNotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool SmsNotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommand>
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommandHandler(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task Handle(UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var existingSettings = await _dbContext.GlobalNotificationSettings.FindAsync(new object[] { request.EventTypeId }, cancellationToken);

        if (existingSettings == null)
        {
            var entity = new GlobalNotificationSettings
            {
                EventTypeId = request.EventTypeId,
                InternalNotificationsEnabled = request.InternalNotificationsEnabled,
                EmailNotificationsEnabled = request.EmailNotificationsEnabled,
                SmsNotificationsEnabled = request.SmsNotificationsEnabled
            };
            
            _dbContext.GlobalNotificationSettings.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            existingSettings.InternalNotificationsEnabled = request.InternalNotificationsEnabled;
            existingSettings.EmailNotificationsEnabled = request.EmailNotificationsEnabled;
            existingSettings.SmsNotificationsEnabled = request.SmsNotificationsEnabled;
        }

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

### Database

```cs
public class EventType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    public ICollection<GlobalNotificationSettings> GlobalNotificationSettings { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class GlobalNotificationSettings
{
    public Guid EventTypeId { get; set; }
    public bool InternalNotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool EmailNotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool SmsNotificationsEnabled { get; set; }
    
    public EventType EventType { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<EventType> EventTypes => Set<EventType>();
    public DbSet<GlobalNotificationSettings> GlobalNotificationSettings => Set<GlobalNotificationSettings>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GlobalNotificationSettings>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(gns => gns.EventTypeId);

            entity.HasOne(et => et.EventType)
                .WithMany(gns => gns.GlobalNotificationSettings)
                .HasForeignKey(gns => gns.EventTypeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });
    }
}
```

### Edit

I did some updates.

By using a transaction, I ensure that the check and insert/update operations are executed atomically, minimizing the risk of race conditions.

```cs
public async Task Handle(UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

    try
    {
        // Check if the provided EventTypeId exists in the EventTypes table
        var eventTypeExists = await _dbContext.EventTypes.AnyAsync(et => et.Id == request.EventTypeId, cancellationToken);

        if (!eventTypeExists)
        {
            // You can return an error or throw a custom exception here
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"EventTypeId {request.EventTypeId} does not exist in the EventTypes table.");
        }

        var existingSettings = await _dbContext.GlobalNotificationSettings.FindAsync(new object[] { request.EventTypeId }, cancellationToken);

        if (existingSettings == null)
        {
            var entity = new GlobalNotificationSettings
            {
                EventTypeId = request.EventTypeId,
                InternalNotificationsEnabled = request.InternalNotificationsEnabled,
                EmailNotificationsEnabled = request.EmailNotificationsEnabled,
                SmsNotificationsEnabled = request.SmsNotificationsEnabled
            };

            _dbContext.GlobalNotificationSettings.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            existingSettings.InternalNotificationsEnabled = request.InternalNotificationsEnabled;
            existingSettings.EmailNotificationsEnabled = request.EmailNotificationsEnabled;
            existingSettings.SmsNotificationsEnabled = request.SmsNotificationsEnabled;
        }

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    // In a concurrent environment, if two transactions try to insert the same EventTypeId simultaneously, one of
    // them will fail because of the foreign key constraint violation. To handle this case, we should catch the
    // exception and rollback the transaction. After rolling back, we can decide how to handle the situation,
    // such as retrying the operation or returning an error.
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);

        // Decide how to handle the situation, such as retrying the operation, returning an error, or throwing a custom exception
        throw new InvalidOperationException("A concurrent operation failed. Please retry the operation.", ex);
    }
}
```

It solves the described issues but there are 3 roundtrips to the database, even though that is happening in a single atomic transaction.

- The first round trip happens when I check if the provided EventTypeId exists in the EventTypes table using the AnyAsync method.
- The second round trip occurs when I attempt to find the existing GlobalNotificationSettings record using the FindAsync method.
- The final round trip is initiated when I call SaveChangesAsync to either insert a new record or update an existing one

The following snippet minimizes the roundtrips to the database to two.

````cs
public async Task Handle(UpsertGlobalNotificationSettingsCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

    try
    {
        var eventTypeAndSettings = await _dbContext.EventTypes
            .Where(et => et.Id == request.EventTypeId)
            .Select(et => new
            {
                EventType = et,
                Settings = et.GlobalNotificationSettings.FirstOrDefault()
            })
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (eventTypeAndSettings?.EventType == null)
        {
            // You can return an error or throw a custom exception here
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"EventTypeId {request.EventTypeId} does not exist in the EventTypes table.");
        }

        if (eventTypeAndSettings.Settings == null)
        {
            var entity = new GlobalNotificationSettings
            {
                EventTypeId = request.EventTypeId,
                InternalNotificationsEnabled = request.InternalNotificationsEnabled,
                EmailNotificationsEnabled = request.EmailNotificationsEnabled,
                SmsNotificationsEnabled = request.SmsNotificationsEnabled
            };

            _dbContext.GlobalNotificationSettings.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            eventTypeAndSettings.Settings.InternalNotificationsEnabled = request.InternalNotificationsEnabled;
            eventTypeAndSettings.Settings.EmailNotificationsEnabled = request.EmailNotificationsEnabled;
            eventTypeAndSettings.Settings.SmsNotificationsEnabled = request.SmsNotificationsEnabled;
        }

        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);

        // You can decide how to handle the situation, such as retrying the operation, returning an error, or throwing a custom exception
        throw new InvalidOperationException("A concurrent operation failed. Please retry the operation.", ex);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Since the existence check and the conditional insert/update happens in two different components that's why your system has a race condition.

Comment: It might happen that the query returns nothing, so you decide to insert, but before you could submit the operation to the db, a concurrent request had been committed to the database so now your insert is not valid anymore.

Comment: @PeterCsala, that's true and it can be optimized into a single query instead of two separate queries for finding and updating/inserting. This is going to fix the race condition issue as it is going to be a single database operation for the upsert, which will handle the check and insert/update in one atomic operation.

Comment: @PeterCsala it is also failing if existingSettings is null and if I have submitted a wrong EventTypeId with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.

 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_GlobalNotificationSettings_EventTypes_EventTypeId". The conflict occurred in database "dev-testdb", table "dbo.EventTypes", column 'Id'.`.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I updated my question which fixes the race condition in the existence check and also the part that fails when existingSettings is null and a non-existing EventTypeId is submitted.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I added a try/catch that rolls back the transaction but it's imperfect. Perhaps I should consider one of the following strategies https://github.com/petercwq/EFCorePractice/blob/master/EFCorePractice/DbContextConcurrencyExtension.cs

Comment: Well, it depends on the requirements how do you need to handle concurrent updates. Either use a hard-coded strategy like server wins (also known as first one wins) Or let the consumer of the client (or an administrator) decide which value should be stored.